# Unknown error facebook graph api iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to fire a request using graph api with the following path `/me/?fields=friends.fields(photos)` but I keep getting `body =     {
        "error_code" = 1;
        "error_msg" = "An unknown error occurred";
    };
    code = 500;`

can somebody please help.

Comment: Same here! Checked `/me?fields=friends.fields(photos)` with all OAuth permissions. API Graph Explorer claims the query is valid.